How do I materialize models from the fivetran/hubspot dbt package?
I followed this guide to materialize hubspot dbt models within my Snowflake database: https://hub.getdbt.com/fivetran/hubspot/latest/
Here is my dbt_project.yml
vars:
    hubspot_database: analytics
    hubspot_schema: hubspot

Here is my packages.yml
# Packages can be found on https://hub.getdbt.com/.
packages:
  - package: dbt-labs/dbt_utils
    version: [">=1.2.0", "<2.0.0"]
  - package: dbt-labs/codegen
    version: [">=0.12.1", "<0.13.0"]
  - package: fivetran/salesforce_formula_utils
    version: [">=0.9.3", "<0.10.0"]
  - package: fivetran/hubspot
    version: [">=0.18.0", "<0.19.0"]


I ran:

dbt deps
dbt run

However, I do not see any hubspot models getting materialized into my snowflake warehouse.
when i run dbt deps i get this log:
13:31:17  Running with dbt=1.8.6
13:31:18  Installing dbt-labs/dbt_utils
13:31:18  Installed from version 1.3.0
13:31:18  Up to date!
13:31:18  Installing dbt-labs/codegen
13:31:18  Installed from version 0.12.1
13:31:18  Up to date!
13:31:18  Installing fivetran/salesforce_formula_utils
13:31:19  Installed from version 0.9.3
13:31:19  Updated version available: 0.10.0
13:31:19  Installing fivetran/hubspot
13:31:19  Installed from version 0.18.0
13:31:19  Up to date!
13:31:19  Installing fivetran/fivetran_utils
13:31:19  Installed from version 0.4.10
13:31:19  Up to date!
13:31:19  Installing fivetran/hubspot_source
13:31:19  Installed from version 0.15.0
13:31:19  Up to date!
13:31:19  Installing dbt-labs/spark_utils
13:31:19  Installed from version 0.3.0
13:31:19  Up to date!

when i run dbt run -s +hubspot, I don't get any errors and a bunch of random models start running, but none of the hubspot ones
Can anyone help?

that's a very incomplete question. please provide more details around what you see. E.g. what logs do you get if you run dbt deps? is the HubSpot package installed correcly? If that's a yes, what logs do you get if you run dbt run -s +hubspot?

@AleixCC I just edited my post. logs for dbt deps shared above. Everything was normal. And I don't get any errors when running dbt run -s +hubspot... but other random models start running instead

what if you run dbt run -s stg_hubspot__deal?

also, what output do you get when running dbt ls --select hubspot --resource-type model?
